# Get a list of all directories and a list of all files on the computer with Scala.

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to get a list of all directories and a list of all files on my computer with Scala. Below are two different ways that I tried to solve the problem. Why am I getting a null pointer exception?

```
def fullDirList(directories: Array[String]): Array[String ] = {
  directories.foldLeft( Array[String]() ){ (x, y) => x ++: fullDirList(getSubDirList(y))
}

def getFullDirList(directories: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
    def loop(dir: Array[String], accDir: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
        if (dir.isEmpty) accDir
        else loop( dir.tail, accDir ++: getFullDirList( getSubDirList( dir.head ) ) )
    } // END loop()
    loop(directories, Array[String]())
} // END getFullDirList()

def getSubDirList(directoryName: String): Array[String] = {
    ( new File(directoryName) ).listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getName )
}

def getFileArray(directoryName: String): Array[String] = {
    ( new File(directoryName) ).listFiles.filter(_.isFile).map(_.getAbsolutePath)
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide information about location of exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up coming up with. Even though I'm sure you could do this with foldRight, I'm just happy that the solution works.

```
def getDirList(directoryName: String): Array[String] = {
    ( new File(directoryName) ).listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getAbsolutePath)
}
def getAllDirs(dir: String): Array[String] = {
    val dirList = getDirList(dir)
    def loop(directories: Array[String], accList: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
        if(directories.isEmpty) accList
        else loop(directories.tail, accList ++: getDirList(directories.head))
    }
    loop(dirList, Array[String]())
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. I knew a lot less back when I was trying to do this program.